Using proportions as a measure of nest success in a glmm
I want to run a GLMM to see if a conservation intervention had an effect on the nesting success of a shore-breeding bird. I'm comparing this against a control where no intervention was used. I used Mayfield's-40% method to get the total nest days (total number of days during which the contents of the nest was alive) for each nest monitored. This number extends from 1-58, 58 being considered a successful breeding attempt (chicks fledged) and anything less than that is considered a failed nest (contents were destroyed in some way).
So I turned that into proportions of survival for each nest, for example, a nest that failed after 14 days would be 14/58. In the glmm (function glmer() in R), my response variable are the proportions, the predictor is the test group (= experimental or contol) and I have two random effects. Because this is 'success-failure' themed data, I have specified family = binomial, but is this appropriate?
model1 <- glmer(Nest_days_proportion ~ Group + (1|Season) + (1|Month),
                data = WFPL, family = binomial)

When I run the model I get warning message:

In eval(family$initialize, rho) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!

Would it be better to run the model using the simple "success" (58/58), "failure" (x<58) data or would it be better to use the numerical proportion data to incorporate variability in the model?

Welcome to Cross ValidatedCan you explain the random structure please ? Regarding the warning it’s probably not a problem

@RobertLong, I think the warning probably is a problem (see my answer) ...

@BenBolker yes I should have used different language (might not be a problem) (+1 for your answer!)

a) not sure why you used a proportion. This changes absolutely nothing because all nest-days are scaled by the same constant. If the scaling was different per nest, that would nortmalize things in some way, but here it is useless (but maybe not a problem, as per other comments). b) you are specifying a binomial model, but not feeding it binomial data (see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/family)

@RobertLong re. random structure, sure: its a nested structure, so my data was collected over 3 breeding seasons (e.g. 2021/2022 season, 2022/2023 season ...) and nests were monitored over various months within each season, depending on when the nest was found. I included them as random factors because I want to ignore the differences between different seasons/years of data collection as well as the effect of climatic differences between months (because nest success is actually better in the warmer months).

Thanks for the info - so you have only 3 seasons ? (1|Season) is not a good idea in that case.

This is a biological aside, why are you indifferent to the interaction between season/month and treatment? If the interventional is equally successful across months, great. If it's only successful in cetain months, great you know when to best use your intervention. You can also then use a fixed rather than random effect model.

@Greg This is a good point. I'd be interested in finding out whether the intervention was more effective over certain months. Would it be appropriate to include unique months (as described below as (1|S_M)) as a random effect and then plain old Month as a fixed effect?

You're nearly there.  To account for the total number of nest days you need to include weights = total_nest_days (or whatever that variable is called in your data set ...); this should allow R to determine that the proportions really do represent ratios of integers, and eliminate the warning (as well as giving you correct answers).
However: rather than use a binomial with the default logit link, I'd recommend you look here for more appropriate models, in particular

the power-logistic link function, which calculates the probability of survival on a given day and raises it to the power of the number of exposure days (modeling overall survival of a particular nest as the independent probability of surviving all days of exposure)
a complementary log-log link function, which I argue in the linked document is a more natural and more computationally convenient way to handle the case of "did/did not survive over an exposure period of $d$ days)

In your case the latter model would be
model1 <- glmer(overall_survival ~ Group + (1|Season) + (1|Month) +
                offset(log(total_nest_days)),
                data = WFPL, family = binomial(link = "cloglog"))

where overall_survival is a 0/1 variable describing whether the nest survived the entire observation period.
Although I should think about this a little bit more, as the methods described here are for cases where we know only that the nest was predated sometime during the exposure period. You might actually want to model this as a discrete-time survival analysis problem (I'm interested in this, you could bug me offline if you wanted)
(If the linked post from 5 years ago is really still the state of the art I should extend it and publish it somewhere more official ...)

Hi Ben, thank you so much for your help and good explanations! I want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly: adding the weights function is essentially the same as turning my total_nest_days into proportions, except that this is directly communicated to R through the function?

With only 3 seasons, I worry about specifying (1|Season)

You're right. I used an ANOVA to test whether there was a difference between the model with and without the term and there was no difference. I will exclude it, thanks @RobertLong

@kmew no worries, happy to help, but you also need to take care in how you code the Month variable, since (for example) January in Season 1 is not the same January in Season 2. The usual way around that is to code the Months as Jan_S1, Jan_S2 etc.... Also, if you exclude Season from the random part you should fit it as a fixed effect instead.

Okay, so I’ve made adjustments to the model following above suggestions:
model2<- glmer(Outcome ~ Group + (1|S_M) +            offset(log(Nest_days_total)),            data = WFPL_updated, family = binomial(link = "cloglog"))
Where (1|S_M) is what @Robert suggested for the Month variable. Now I get the following error which I see can be a result of many kinds of issues:
Error: (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate
Do you have any suggestions??

How many unique S_M do you have ? I think you also need Season as a fixed effect.  Does it converge without the offset. What happens if you use GLMMadaptive::mixed_model() and glmmTMB::glmmTMB()

ugh, that's the only problem with cloglog, it tends to be less numerically stable ... you could try the same model with glmmTMB (should be a drop-in replacement) and see how it goes ...
